# Remove 'don't add these answers' from community wiki question

Tags: discussion

I assume that this question: [What web browsers are there for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44326/what-web-browsers-are-there-for-ubuntu) is supposed to become a list of browsers, one browser per answer.

The origional poster added

> I know about Firefox and Google chrome, you don't need to add them as answers

but if I'm right in thinking the question is now a "list ALL the browsers" question, adding those 2 might be good for completeness?

I would suggest to remove the sentence, leaving the way open for someone to add these 2 popular browsers to our list, but I'm not sure if that is changing the question too much?

Comment: This is why poll questions make no sense on the site, voting to close.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I can't agree more. Why leave out the common obvious ones? They may not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: I agree with @gertvdijk, but I would take it one further and say that I would edit Firefox and Chrome out of the question.  And I did.

Comment: Check the edit history.  There used to be a note "Don't list Chrome or Firefox."

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing Whoops. missed that. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The point of Stack Exchange is to create reusable questions and answers that benefit many people (or at least as many as are interested in the topic they cover).

Therefore, and without intending any disrespect, it's irrelevant that the OP already knows about Firefox and Chrome. That would be a good reason for *the OP* to pre-emptively post answers about them. It is not a good reason to restrict the scope of the answer in such a specific and artificial way.

With that said, there are *very, very many* web browsers out there. I suspect this should be considered a "big list" question and closed (and perhaps locked for posterity / historical interest, so it is not deleted). Which web browsers are listed there will always be arbitrary and the list is unlikely to be maintained well.

But whether or not we're going to close it, yeah, editing out the Chrome/FF restriction (which I am taken to understand has now been done) was the right thing to do.